# What is the common tool to accomplish this art

Tags: tools, style

I have come across this art on dribbble and really love it.

I am not a graphic design guru but I really want to try to paint it with with my Wacom board. The question is, which tool shall I use as a beginner?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfNQV.jpg]

Image from [StudioMUTI](https://dribbble.com/studioMUTI) on Dribble

Comment: That's not a graph...just an illustration. Appears to be vector based, so likely done with Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape or the like.

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 diferent questions there.
The *ilustration* you are showing is probably a **vector based** file. A list can be Corel Draw, Ilustrator, Inkscape (open source), Serif Draw plus (free), and in my opinion they are easier to use with a normal mouse, but there are some interesting things you can do drawing freely with your board.

The second question could be What aplication do you recomend to start using my wacom board? If you like the "natural paint look" you can try http://mypaint.intilinux.com/ (free) or http://www.painterartist.com/rw/. But this aplications has a totaly diferent look that the one you posted.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for anyone to tell what was used to create that. Could be Illustrator, Inkscape, Photoshop, Gimp, Paintshop Pro, Pixelator or any one of thousands of applications.

If I, personally were creating something similar, I'd use Adobe Illustrator. But that doesn't make that the "right' or "correct" application to be used.

If you want an answer, you'll have to ask the artist who created it.

Answer (score 0):

I see a different question here that would be more suitable to ask: "How can I get used to using and illustrating with my new drawing tablet?"

For that, I'll first post two links. The first one deals with getting setup and used to simply handling your new tablet and the second gives a selection of tutorials that are great for getting used to actually creating art with it:

http://design.tutsplus.com/articles/4-easy-ways-to-break-in-your-new-tablet--psd-14436

http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/articles/25-tutorials-for-getting-started-with-your-wacom-tablet

My main tip is, as is mentioned in the first link, to just get started. Use your pen and tablet for everything you use your computer for, get to know the tools, customize the buttons etc. to suit your needs. Secondly I'd recommend just using whatever software you have that makes use of the tablet's features to start making stuff. That's the best way to learn after all, just creating and iterating.